# Use class methods output in other methods from the same class

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

The objective is to use the output dataframe from the method `readData` in the method `MissingData`. My question is how to connect the methods together so that their outputs can be used in the different methods?

```
import pandas as pd 


class DATAA():

    def __init__(self,dataset,name,path=None):

        self.dataset = dataset
        self.name= name
        self.path= path

    def readData(self):
        outputdf = pd.read_csv(self.dataset, sep = ',') 
        return  outputdf

    def MissingData (outputdf):

        Missing_values = outputdf.isna.sum() 

        return Missing_values


df = DATAA(dataset,name)
df.readData()
df.MissingData()
```

Comment: I would do something like `self.df = outputdf` inside `readData`, and modify the signature of `MissingData` like `def MissingData(self)`. Then you could use outputdf by accessing `self.df`

Comment: I think you are confusing instance, class and static methods. A class method needs to be declared with a syntactic sugar notation before the signature, `@classmethod\ndef MissingData(cls, outputdf): ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do this due to OOP standards, but alternatively, you can achieve this by creating a class method using the `@classmethod` decorator, creating a `class variable` to store output from that function, and then referencing that `class variable` using the `self` keyword. In the following code, you can reference to class variable in `MissingData()`. This is the only way to use class methods output in other methods from the same class.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd 

class DATAA():
    outputdf = None

    def __init__(self,dataset,name,path=None):
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.name= name
        self.path= path

    @classmethod
    def readData(cls, dataset):
        cls.outputdf = pd.read_csv(dataset, sep = ',')

    def MissingData(self):
        Missing_values = self.outputdf.isna.sum()
        return Missing_values


df = DATAA(dataset, name)
df.readData(df.dataset)
missing_data = df.MissingData()
print(missing_data)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I have a question, Im confused that in the classmethod readData we used cls.outputdf and the method MissingData we used self.outputdf. Does that mean that classmethod are considered as self variable?

Comment: I created 3 instances based on the base class DATAA. The thing is, when  I call the method MissingData for each instance the outputdf which is the result of the method readData is the same for the 3 instances- it seems that the output from that readData (class method) stores the last result of last applied instance- Do you have an idea to avoid this? thank you again

Comment: Yes, class variables are sharable, meaning they has same value for all instances. In order to make independent variables then you can use instances variables, I can help you with that as well, just let me know than I'll edit the answer. But for now, your question was related to the use of class methods, so my answer perfectly align with that. Many Thanks

Comment: thank you so much for your contribution I slowly understand the concept now due to your help- I also will be happy if you could help me to use the instances variables- many thanks again